# How to notify if has any item been added and what specific item has been added to a state in Vuex store represented by a Map?

Tags: vue.js, dictionary, vuex, watch

I have a Map named "activeCharts" in a Vuex as a state. Key is an ID of a chart and value is some stuff about that chart. In my application are charts adding, removing or their value is being modified. Is there any way, how to get the change after every change of the Map "activeCharts" in Vuex proceeded by clicking on any chart? I need to extract values hidden in Map value.

This is my state in Vuex ->
Computed and Watch are in a component.

```
activeCharts: new Map()

computed: {
    activeCharts: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.chart.activeCharts;
      }
    },
    activeChartsSize: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.chart.activeCharts.size;
      }
    },
 }

watch: {
    activeCharts: {
      deep: true,
      handler : function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
          console.log("Maps are different")
          console.log(oldValue)
          console.log(newValue)
        }
      }
    },
   activeChartsSize: {
      handler: function (newSize, oldSize) {
      console.log("Old size : ",oldSize)
      console.log("New size: ",newSize)
  }
}
 }
```

I'm trying to use watch on "activeCharts" with newValue and oldValue, but seems to be same after any interaction with charts, without any change.

If I watch an activeChart.size, changes are perfectly seen. Every time I add a chart into a map, console logs the current number of active charts.

How can I extract changes after is any chart added or modified?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. The question lacks the actual code. It's unknown which Vue version you use.

Answer (score 0):

its just a refference thing, here is explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208453/21264345

and here demo for vue 2 https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-demo-vue-3-forked-fgqhkv?file=/src/App.vue